# Get a range of columns in JMP Script

Tags: scripting, sas-jmp

I am just starting JMP scripting and am having trouble finding the syntax for performing a function on a range of columns without manually looping. I am trying to do a simple sum() across a row, but want to skip the first 5 columns. 
I have tried various arrangements of the code below.

```
dt1=open();
colSize=ncol(dt1);
Show(colSize);
dt1 << new column("is_empty",numeric, formula(isMissing(sum(/*column(5):colSize */)))),EvalFormula);
```

I'm open to creating a list before hand, but have not found out how to create one dynamically (first 5 columns are always the same, but number/names of columns varies) without manually looping.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `Summation` which is only one step removed from manually looping:

```
Local({c}, Summation( c = 6,  N Col(), Column( c )[Row()] ));
```

Or you can use `Get Column Names` to get all the columns, and then use the range subscript to get the subset you want before passing it to `Sum`:

```
Sum( (Current Data Table() << Get Column Names())[6 :: N Col()] );
```